# CGContext drawing in wrong part of UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an app which allows the user to take a photo and draw on that photo by dragging their finger (like Snapchat).  I am very close to making that functionality work, but I am having an issue which I believe is somehow related to the contentMode of the UIImageView which is messing up the location of my line.  It is most noticeable at the edges of the screen.  If I use scaleAspectFill and attempt to trace the edges of the screen with my finger, I see the following:

[image]

As you can see, the lines on the left and on the bottom are off the screen.  If I use scaleAspectFit and do the same thing, this is the result:

[image]

In this case, the left and bottom are correct and the right/top are incorrect.  My code for the drawing is below:

```
var lastPoint:CGPoint!
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    if self.capturedImageView.isHidden == false && self.isDrawing {
        self.lastPoint = CGPoint(x: touches.first!.location(in: self.capturedImageView).x, y: touches.first!.location(in: self.capturedImageView).y)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    if (self.capturedImageView.isHidden == false && lastPoint != nil && self.isDrawing) {
        self.capturedImageView.image = self.drawLine(onImage: self.capturedImageView.image!, fromPoint: CGPoint(x: touches.first!.location(in: self.capturedImageView).x, y: touches.first!.location(in: self.capturedImageView).y), toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
        self.lastPoint = CGPoint(x: touches.first!.location(in: self.capturedImageView).x, y: touches.first!.location(in: self.capturedImageView).y)
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    self.lastPoint = nil
}

//drawLine creates a new UIImage with the desired line drawn on it, 
//which I then use to replace capturedImageView.image
func drawLine(onImage: UIImage, fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage {

    // Create a context of the starting image size and set it as the current one
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(onImage.size)

    // Draw the starting image in the current context as background
    onImage.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

    // Get the current context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // Draw a red line
    context.setLineWidth(5.0)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.move(to: fromPoint)
    context.addLine(to: toPoint)
    context.strokePath()

    // Save the context as a new UIImage
    let myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Return modified image
    return myImage!
}
```

I assume that I am going wrong because the coordinates of the touch in the UIImageView itself are different from the coordinates within the UIImageView's image. I am really stumped on how to fix this, though.  How can I get the touch's location in capturedImageView.image instead of just capturedImageView?

Comment: I'd do all this on a transparent UIView that sits atop the image view.  I'd have that view keep an array of strokes (start, end), and I'd stroke those in the view's drawRect: method.

Comment: @danh The issue with that solution is that I want to save these strokes into the UIImage so that the user can send it.  So just displaying the strokes on top of the image isn't enough, I need them to actually become part of the image.